# форматирование текста telegram bot на php

Tags: php, html, telegram-bot

пишу телеграм бота на php. в telegram bot api есть опция `parse_mode` которая форматирует текст как `html` или `markdown`. при внесении такой опции, она никак не влияет на вывод. ни положительно, ни отрицательно. 
вот эта команда:
`$testmes=$website."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chatId."&parse+mode=html&text=<b>Hello</b>\r\n<i>How are you?</i>";
  file_get_contents($testmes);`

выводит это: `<b>Hello</b>__<i>How are you?</i>`

в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Вы пишете что должно быть `parse_mode`, а дальше в коде у вас уже `parse+mode`. Может в опечатке проблема?

Comment: да, вы правы. исправил. но он уже выводит это **Hello**___How are you?_ новая строка не работает

Comment: Попробуйте текст обернуть через функцию urlencode, а так же замените \r\n на \n

Comment: Если без urlencode, то можно заменить \n на %0A, а \r на %0D

Comment: замена на %0A помогла. спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первая проблема в вашем коде, это опечатка. Нужно писать не `parse+mode`, a `parse_mode`. Но исправив ее не будет работать переход на новую строку, и не только. Также вероятнее всего будут проблемы с русскими символами. Для того чтобы избежать этого следует воспользоваться функцией urlencode:

```
$testmessage="<b>Hello</b>\n<i>How are you?</i>";
$testmes=$website."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chatId."&parse_mode=html&text=".urlencode($testmessage);
file_get_contents($testmes);
```