# Как форматировать текст в telegram bot? PHP

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Бот отправляет строку `$txt = "Foo bar";` Есть желание слово **bar** выделить жирным. В простых переписках в телеге достаточно окружить слово двумя парами звездочек и дело в шляпе. Однако бот звездочки просто распечатывает в тексте

Вопрос, как можно отформатировать текст (выделить жирным и/или пометить как гиперссылка)?

Пробовал экранировать звездочки, пробовал юзать html теги и олдскульные [bb], но без результата.

Comment: в документации вполне же написано.... там два типа сообщений может  быть (parse_mode) markdown и html.... и правида там соответствующие этим самым типам  ............ https://core.telegram.org/bots/update56kabdkb12ibuisabdubodbasbdaosd

Comment: описание сообщений - https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#updating-messages 
 и форматирование оных - https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options

Comment: Спасибо @АлексейШиманский , разобрался! ```parse_mode HTML``` решил все мои проблемы!

Comment: Возможно вам поможет этот вопрос:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/688738/%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-telegram-bot-%d0%bd%d0%b0-php/688787#688787

Comment: Спасибо большое!